# OnModelCreating - forcing new creation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

In some situations, during the application run, I need to turn on identity insert:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

But, since OnModelCreating is executed only once, what would be the best way to achieve this? Is it possible to recreate model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OnModelCreating will always be called only once. If you need to recreate model you must manually create `DbModelBuilder`.

```
var builder = new DbModelBuilder(DbModelBuilderVersion.Latest);
// setup whole model
DbModel model = builder.Build(connection);
DbCompiledModel compiledModel = model.Compile();
// cache compiledModel for future usage - compilation is very expensive

var context = new DbContext(compiledModel);
```

You should try to avoid this. Identity insert doesn't work very well with EF so you will most probably have to insert data directly with SQL and that doesn't need changing the mapping.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, is there someinformation why is identity insert not working well with EF? I have done some testings using the method I posted in my question, and didn't noticed any problems so far. If you have some information, I would be very thankful to hear it. I was also thinking about using Sql server queries, but I am trying to avoid it, since if I change any of the entity properties names, for example, this import would fail when using queries, while if I use DbContext, I do not need to pay attention to this problem.

Comment: I am unable to make this work. when I use build  mehtod, I am passing an SqlConnection connection object. At this point, connection.Open() works without a problem. After I compile model, and pass it to my DbContext, I receive an error (from Sql server log): Login failed for user 'Server-PC\TestUser'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'TestProject.Data.MyDbContext'. Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.[CLIENT: <local machine>].

Comment: I forgot to add this: Why does ModelBuilder in this case tries to connext to database by using context name, and not the correct database name from the connection object? The connection string I am ysing is : "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

Comment: It seems that constructor that takes both connection string and compiled model must be used, intead of just passing compiled model.